# Ignorning an Anchor in a JScript search function

Tags: html, jscript

I have this function for searching a table and displaying the rows that match my search input

```
function searchTable() {
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make one of the strings in the data clickable with a hyper link.
However this affects my search because the the   link is inside my  table data . So even thought it is not visible it is skewing the search results.

What argument could I add to my function to ignore the contents of my  bracket and still find the text string in my table. Or how could I place my anchor outside my table data brackets and still have the string be a clickable anchor.

Ex of table row:

```
 <tr>
    <td><a href="K:\Gestion des Risques\Manuel de tarification\1.TABLEAU DE BORD\2. Invalidité\1. Médical\0. Index A-Z\Abces_au_cerveau.pdf" target"_blank">Abcès au cerveau</a></td>
    <td>Neurologique</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Sorry beginner question. I am also looking for an argument to highlight the results of my search if anyone has it.